# Platform Policy 8.2 Violation?

Tags: ios, facebook, sdk, facebook-login, policy

Our app is currently being restricted by Facebook because they state that we are violating policy 8.2. The following is the content of the policy and their suggestion:

```
Your app does not have functioning link to your privacy policy on the Apple App Store. Here's visual example of the policy: https://developers.facebook.com/policy#2-7-photo.

Platform Policy 8.2: Native iOS and Android apps that implement Facebook Login must use our official SDKs for Login. 

Please make sure your iOS app is using the most recent version of our SDK for Login. You can find more information on our iOS SDK for Login and other Login-related products here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios.

You can see our visual example for this policy here: https://developers.facebook.com/policy#7-2-photo.
```

Although our `Podfile` has the contents `pod 'FBSDKLoginKit', '~> 4.7'`, our `Podfile.lock` specifies `FBSDKLoginKit (4.38.1)`, which matches the `Podfile.lock` contents of a test project we made and installed the `FBSDKLoginKit` pod in. What exactly are we supposed to change? The only other thing we can think of is that our App Dashboard keeps suggesting us to upgrade to the latest Facebook SDK; do we have to configure something there?

Comment: 4.38.1 was released in October last year: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-objc-sdk/commit/1c0209b2c20d43e98a4166418dedab769a96e020#diff-abafd6c211c0ae63013963850e28e0ed

Current version seems to be 4.40 https://github.com/facebook/facebook-objc-sdk/blob/master/FBSDKLoginKit.podspec#L6

Comment: Thanks WizKid. I went to the Github repo you linked for 4.40 and added the `CoreKit`, `LoginKit`, and `ShareKit` pods to my `Podfile` like README states, but when I run `pod install`, the `Podfile.lock` defaults to `4.38.1` for all three of them. Should I have to specify `4.40` in my `Podfile`?